# How do I load a view controller in advance if I know the user will most likely select it soon?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiviewcontroller

In my app, some studies I've done show that when the user views an article, the vast majority of the time (85%+) they load the accompanying comments view controller that goes along with the article.

I'd love to load this view controller while they're reading the article, so when they tap the comments button to transition to the comments view controller the view controller is ready without any loading times.

How would I go about accomplishing something like this? At the moment when the user taps the button I call `performSegueWithIdentifier:` and pass it the identifier I set in the Storyboard.

And obviously, for the cases where the user decides to go back to the root view controller (say, a list of articles) I'd want to cancel the loading of that comments view controller as it would be wasteful to continue at that point.

Comment: Do you believe that loading the comments view controller in advance provides a performance benefit? What is the cost of only loading it at the time that the user requests it? I think your idea is worth pursuing; I'm mainly curious about the benefit you expect to provide.

Comment: @bneely presumably the comments are stored server-side... I would think that querying the database while the user reads the article would significantly reduce the load time of the comments view controller.

Comment: Yes, my thinking is also about external resources. I'm thinking that @Aloha64 should instead look at prefetching model data.

Comment: @bneely I see what you mean - the load time of the view controller itself would be insignificant compared to the time spent waiting for the query to return.

Comment: @bneely While that is indeed the vast majority of the overheard, the view controller is brought in via a gesture (the user slides the new view controller in) so it being loaded before the user has to slide it in would be preferable, as I'm predicting a hiccup in the sliding gesture while the view controller puts together all its contents.

Comment: I use a similar sliding gesture to trigger a segue in my app and there is no noticeable delay caused by instantiating the destination view controller. Views take up a reasonable amount of memory, so I would recommend that you take @bneely's advice and focus on starting your query while the user is reading the article. I will post an answer shortly explaining one way to pass a list of comments into your destination view controller.

Comment: That'd be fantastic. I'll also investigate performance surrounding that gesture, but your claim as to no noticeable delay occurring is great to hear. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

If you keep the data model separate from the UI, you shouldn't have any trouble creating the views on the fly, and almost nothing to gain from creating them earlier.

A reasonably standard approach is to bring the view in with blank or filler data, and have the data call go out to the middle tier, with asynchronous handlers processing callbacks.

This is much easier with the block based completion handlers available in the iOS 7 flavored NSURLSession, and only slightly harder with NSURLConnection (which listens for responses on the main thread, but can be thrown into the background once you catch the response).

So my advice would be to focus on backgrounding the data calls and responses, and strongly differentiate between displaying UI and populating the UI with data. If your data manager is separate from your View Controller, nothing is stopping you from "pre-fetching" the data a little early, and then potentially having it ready when the ViewController needs it. It's a perfectly normal load balancing / customer experience technique for high value data.

Comment: I guess I could be more specific to your given situation, here's one possible approach: When the article loads, you tell your data manager to fetch and store the comments. When the user taps the "comments" button, you load the UI and populate it with the stored comments (if any, server may not have responded yet...) and make a new call to check for any newer comments made after you pre-fetched, updating the UI with those asynchronously as they arrive. I'm glazing over some details and some tedious coordination work you have to manage, but that's the basic idea.

Answer (score 0):

The solution I'm about to describe is a bit of a hack - it doesn't really conform to the proper model-view-controller design pattern that Ryan mentioned. That being said, it might give you an idea about how to proceed. Perhaps you can improve on it to make it cleaner.

First, define a `@protocol` in the App Delegate. Let's call this protocol `CommentQueryDelegate`; it should define a method called `-(void)handleCommentQuery`. Also give your App Delegate a strong property to store the comment data and a weak property to store a delegate object, like so:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray* arrayOfComments;
@property (nonatomic, weak) id<CommentQueryDelegate> commentQueryDelegateObject;
```

Make sure to initialize the both of these properties to `nil`.

Somewhere in the article view controller, use `dispatch_async()` to asynchronously query your database and retrieve the comments while the user is reading the article:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^
{
    AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

    // query your database here

    appDelegate.arrayOfComments = [NSMutableArray array];
    [appDelegate.arrayOfComments addObject:@"someComment"];

    [appDelegate.commentQueryDelegateObject handleCommentQuery];
}
```

If the query is completed before the user segues into the comments view, the `handleCommentQuery` message will be sent to the `nil` object, which will have no effect.

Now, in the comments view controller's `viewDidLoad` method, set the `commentQueryDelegateObject` property of the App Delegate to `self`. You will need to specify that the comments view controller conforms to the comment query protocol. Next, check to see if the App Delegate's `arrayOfComments` property is `nil`. If it isn't, great - display the comments immediately. Otherwise, display a `UIActivityIndicatorView`.

Implement the `-(void)handleCommentQuery` method in your comments view controller. This method should disable the activity indicator and display the comments.

One final thing to consider - the strong pointer to the `arrayOfComments` object will keep it from being deallocated, so you should set this pointer to `nil` once you're done with your article view controller.